# Function of this matrix

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix M=$ \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I find $ \cos ({Mπ \over 6})$

Comment: do you know how to perform a matrix exponential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Begin by diagonalizing.  We have $M = UDU^T$ where
$$
D = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&1}, \quad U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}
$$

Comment: This was useful! 
Does this work whenever I need to find function of a matrix?

Comment: It works so long as $M$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example and you can apply it to your case. To arrive to the concept of cosinus of a matrix you need to think about power series for the cosine and call the sum the cosine of A.

In general (if $A$ is a matrix, let's say 2x2):

$cos(A)=I_{2x2}-\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{4!}A^4-...$

(where $I_{2\times2}$ is the identity matrix)

So you can apply that to your matrix by putting $M$ instead of $A$ and after you can multiply the elements of the matrix by $\pi/6$.

I hope this will help you